# Generated PDF is blank when using epstopdf

Tags: graphics, epstopdf

I'm writing a TeX document in which graphics are converted from `.eps` to `.pdf` using `epstopdf`.

For the most part, everything works fine, but for two of the figures, the pdf that is generated from the eps file (i.e. `figure-eps-converted-to.pdf`) is completely blank.

The result is a normal document but with a blank image in place of these two graphics.

EDIT: The figures were both created in MatLab, before subsequent editing in Adobe Illustrator.

Does anyone know of an element of the package `epstopdf` that would stop it from properly converting my `.eps` file? The TeX code to include these graphics is exactly the same as for the those that work fine.

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Can you provide us with access to the two figures that are giving a problem?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'd be happy to provide the figures, is there someway I can upload the .eps files?

Comment: Sure, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/15925 and note the proceedure for those who do not have sufficient reputation yet.

Comment: @GMacGilchrist --- Unfortunately the image upload on this site uses the `png` format, which means that the information we need in order to help you is lost. If you can make the `eps` file available for download somewhere, you can add a link to your question. Incidentally, my money is on Illustrator as the culprit. It is the work of Satan.

Comment: @IanThompson Yes, I noted the .png issue while uploading. I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently technically minded to make the plots available for download, so will try to solve the problem independently. Incidentally, TeXnicCenter completes the conversion absolutely fine - any ideas what the difference could be between this and the distribution I generally use (TeXShop) which fluffs it??

Comment: @GMacGilchrist --- If you are really stuck, you can email them to me (click my name to get my address) and I will post them for you. TeXShop and TeXnicCenter are just front ends that use other utilities to convert postscript to pdf. If you dig around in the menus you should be able to find out exactly what each is doing.

Comment: @IanThompson Many thanks for your attempts to help. I tried a number of options (in terms of where I was converting the files, and how the images were being built) with nothing working. I think the problem is something to do with the defined border in the .eps image, which seems to be a common problem when converting to .pdf in certain programs. I've circumvented the problem by the unsatisfactory method of converting the files to .pdf in Illustrator before importing them to the TeX document.